# Autofac lifetime scope issue with asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, autofac, lifetime-scoping

I'm having an issue with the lifetime scope of autofac lasting across a request in an asp.net webforms site.

I'm register a factory in auto fac thus:

```
builder.RegisterType<DoSomethingFactory>().As<IDoSomethingFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This occurs in the app_start of course.

then I have a simple user control that calls a method of this factory

```
IDoSomethingFactory doSomethingFactory = Resolver.Resolve<IDoSomethingFactory>();
Number.Text = doSomethingFactory.DoSomething().ToString();
```

I have two instances of this control on a page, so that the DoSomething method should be called twice and the factory should be resolved twice also.

The first time I run the site, the contstructor for the DoSomethingFactory is fired, and there are 2 subsequent calls to the DoSomething method.  The second request, results in 2 calls to the DoSomething method without a fresh new-ing up of the factory.

If I take out the InstancePerLifetimeScope on the registering then the factory is instantiated on each resolve.  Most answers I have seen for this talk about an MVC site.  I also have an MVC site and am using it in the same manner and it is working as requested, hence the need to question for asp.net webforms

To be clear I would like the factory to be instantiated once every request.  Any help or ideas would be welcome.

Many thanks

Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have one instance of your `DoSomethingFactory` per request you need to use the `InstancePerHttpRequest` extension method.

From the Autofac wiki: [WebFormsIntegration](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebFormsIntegration)

> ASP.NET integration adds a special component lifetime that allows a component instance to live for the life of a single HTTP request. You can register components using the `InstancePerHttpRequest()` extension method in the `Autofac.Integration.Web` namespace.

So change your registration to:

```
builder.RegisterType<DoSomethingFactory>()
       .As<IDoSomethingFactory>()
       .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```